# Social Media Icons Under Button in Header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

this is what my social media links and button looks like right now.

[image]

But I want to move the button above the social media links.  Preferably right in the middle of the 5.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-3 branding">
        <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
            <img alt="awesomeinternet Internet Services" src="{{var protoHost}}img/awesomeInternet.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-0">
      <p class="socialmediaspacer headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:613-865-7733" style="color: black"> 613-865-7733</a></p>
      <p class="headercontact headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="mailto:info@awesomeinternet.ca" style="color: black"></i> info@awesomeinternet.ca</a></p>
    </div>
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer brandingspacer" href="https://www.facebook.com/awesomeinternetInternetService"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color:#3B5998"></i></a>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://twitter.com/awesomeinternetcanada"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color:#1da1f2"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.instagram.com/awesomeinternetinternet/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color:#623628"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_EH7RNVnL7IUch12iHzFAQ"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" style="color:#E62B24"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://plus.google.com/116264661972220598755"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" style="color:#DB4437"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 buttonspacer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">My Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
html{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Roboto";
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
a{
    color:#00A0F0;
}
.spacer{
    height:70px;
    width: 100%;
}
.socialspacer {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}
.AccountButton {
  padding-left: 730px;
}
.smallspacer{
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacer-1{width:100%;height:10px;}.spacer-2{width:100%;height:20px;}.spacer-3{width:100%;height:30px;}.spacer-4{width:100%;height:40px;}
.spacer-5{width:100%;height:50px;}.spacer-6{width:100%;height:60px;}.spacer-7{width:100%;height:70px;}.spacer-8{width:100%;height:80px;}
.spacer-9{width:100%;height:90px;}.spacer-10{width:100%;height:100px;}.spacer-11{width:100%;height:110px;}.spacer-12{width:100%;height:120px;}

.locationTitle{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    color:#007dd1;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
.Location {
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-right: 300px;
}
.subTitle{
    text-align: center;
}
.subHead{
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: .6em;
}
.navbar{
    height: 100px;
    background-color:
}
.navbar>.container-fluid{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid>*{
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid img{
    height: 100px;
}
.branding *{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #007dd1
}
.headerspacer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.socialmediaspacer {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.navbartext {
      padding-top: 17px;
      padding-left: 277px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 17px;
}
.navbarspacer{
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.brandingspacer {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.contactspacer {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.InternetSpacer {
  height: 45px;
}
.buttonspacer {
  margin-right: -100px;
}
.InfoSpacer {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.inlineParagraph {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
.headercontact {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.centerlinks {
  text-align: center;
}
.navIcon{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #0071bd;
}
.navbar > li > a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #CDF;
}
.navbar li:not(.navSep):hover{
    margin: 0 0 -2px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navSep{
    width:2px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
    background-color: #A9AFDD;
}

.imgCon{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;

}
.imgCon img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    div[aria-expanded="true"] .navSep{
        display: none;
    }
}

.mainTitle{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
}

.extraInfo{
    background-color: #333;
    color:white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px grey;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.footer{
  background-color: #007dd1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}
.footer a{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.footer p{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
@media (min-width : 1200px) {
    .col-xl-0{display:none;}

}
@media (max-width : 1200px){
    .col-lg-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 992px){
    .col-md-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 768px){
    .col-sm-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 480px){
    .col-xs-0{display:none;}
    .page {
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .footer {
      height: 100px;
    }
    .Location {
        padding-left: 140px;
        padding-right: 260px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px){
  .Location {
      padding-left: 70px;
      padding-right: 260px;
  }
  .page {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 160px;
  }
}




@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your css doesn't exactly match what is in your html classes.  I would start by putting the button div above the social media divs, and since you're using left padding to determine where it is.. you can play with that, or set a width to the account button div, and center the content.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Roboto";
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
a{
    color:#00A0F0;
}
.spacer{
    height:70px;
    width: 100%;
}
.socialspacer {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 38px;
}
.AccountButton {
  padding-left: 730px;
}
.smallspacer{
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}
.spacer-1{width:100%;height:10px;}.spacer-2{width:100%;height:20px;}.spacer-3{width:100%;height:30px;}.spacer-4{width:100%;height:40px;}
.spacer-5{width:100%;height:50px;}.spacer-6{width:100%;height:60px;}.spacer-7{width:100%;height:70px;}.spacer-8{width:100%;height:80px;}
.spacer-9{width:100%;height:90px;}.spacer-10{width:100%;height:100px;}.spacer-11{width:100%;height:110px;}.spacer-12{width:100%;height:120px;}

.locationTitle{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    color:#007dd1;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-top: 24px;
}
.Location {
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-right: 300px;
}
.subTitle{
    text-align: center;
}
.subHead{
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: .6em;
}
.navbar{
    height: 100px;
    background-color:
}
.navbar>.container-fluid{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid>*{
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar>.container-fluid img{
    height: 100px;
}
.branding *{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #007dd1
}
.headerspacer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.socialmediaspacer {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.navbartext {
      padding-top: 17px;
      padding-left: 277px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 17px;
}
.navbarspacer{
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.brandingspacer {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.contactspacer {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.InternetSpacer {
  height: 45px;
}
.buttonspacer {
  margin-right: -100px;
}
.InfoSpacer {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.inlineParagraph {
  float:left;
  display:inline;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
.headercontact {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.centerlinks {
  text-align: center;
}
.navIcon{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #0071bd;
}
.navbar > li > a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #CDF;
}
.navbar li:not(.navSep):hover{
    margin: 0 0 -2px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.navSep{
    width:2px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
    background-color: #A9AFDD;
}

.imgCon{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:100%;

}
.imgCon img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.page{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    div[aria-expanded="true"] .navSep{
        display: none;
    }
}

.mainTitle{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: white;
}

.extraInfo{
    background-color: #333;
    color:white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px grey;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.footer{
  background-color: #007dd1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: right;
}
.footer a{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.footer p{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.margin-adjust{
  margin-top:-35px;
}
@media (min-width : 1200px) {
    .col-xl-0{display:none;}

}
@media (max-width : 1200px){
    .col-lg-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 992px){
    .col-md-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 768px){
    .col-sm-0{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width : 480px){
    .col-xs-0{display:none;}
    .page {
      padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .footer {
      height: 100px;
    }
    .Location {
        padding-left: 140px;
        padding-right: 260px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px){
  .Location {
      padding-left: 70px;
      padding-right: 260px;
  }
  .page {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 160px;
  }
}




@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Roboto Bold'), local('Roboto-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-3 branding">
        <a class="imgCon" href="{{var protoHost}}">
            <img alt="awesomeinternet Internet Services" src="{{var protoHost}}img/awesomeInternet.png">
        </a>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-7 margin-adjust">

    <div class="col-xs-0">
      <p class="socialmediaspacer headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:613-865-7733" style="color: black"> 613-865-7733</a></p>
      <p class="headercontact headerspacer inlineParagraph"><i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="mailto:info@awesomeinternet.ca" style="color: black"></i> info@awesomeinternet.ca</a></p>
    </div>
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer brandingspacer" href="https://www.facebook.com/awesomeinternetInternetService"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" style="color:#3B5998"></i></a>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://twitter.com/awesomeinternetcanada"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color:#1da1f2"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.instagram.com/awesomeinternetinternet/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color:#623628"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_EH7RNVnL7IUch12iHzFAQ"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" style="color:#E62B24"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-0">
        <a class="inlineParagraph socialspacer" href="https://plus.google.com/116264661972220598755"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" style="color:#DB4437"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 buttonspacer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ">My Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please check and correct if any styling for low resolutions and use .